# How to Retrive the last Updated Record in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi Can you please help me for this scenario,

Table: Mail_Archives

```
 Mail_ID     Archived_by         Archived_date
   001        Sam                21/11/2011
   002        Tina               10/10/2012
   002        Tina               10/10/2012
   004        Zark               10/10/2011
```

How to form a query for this output, I need the query result for the recent archived date including the count. For Example

```
  Count      Archived_by     Archived_Date

   2          Tina           10/10/2012
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select * from (
   select * from Mail_Archives order by Archived_date desc
) where rownum=1
```

**Update**:

```
select count(a.Mail_ID) top_one, b.archived_by, b.archived_date 
from Mail_Archives a, 
    (select * from (
           select * from Mail_Archives order by Archived_date desc
        ) where rownum=1
    ) b
where a.archived_by = b.archived_by 
group by b.archived_by, b.archived_date
```

You can see that it works [**here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2178a/6)

Comment: Hi Yes its working well, but i Need the count for latest Archived_Date

Comment: The count of what ? the count of all the updates that were preformed by the same user who updated the last record ? what if that same user had an update two years ago - should that update count as well ? you should define a good criteria

Comment: IF You see in my sample table, in Archived_BY there has two records in the name of TINA, so i need the count along with latest archived_Date and archived_by

Comment: I tried like this, but i cannot get exact output, SELECT COUNT(*) AS arch_cnt,  MAX(TO_CHAR(archived_date,'DD-Mon-YYYY')),MAX(ARCHIVED_BY) as arch_date FROM Mail_Archives WHERE Mail_ID     LIKE upper('002')

Comment: Pls check this link, i have slightly modified the structure http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3bcbd/1                                         In my sample the count is coming as "1" but my expected result is "2" becuase Mail Id "002" Having two entries, can you please help me for this

Comment: @SANJAY per the comment I posted below your question, if you find an answer helpful - you should check it as "accepted" by clicking the "check"-sign below the number to the top left of the answer. Also, if you found other answers to be constructive, you can "upvote" them by clicking the "up arrow" above that number.

Answer (score 0):

This is an MySQL query, I don't have Oracle to test it, but it might give you a good try.
Note: table name as 'test'.
The LIMIT 1 will take only the top one (show max count )
Upper or lower case in table attributes makes no difference in a query, also, the 00 before an integer will be truncated by default

```
SELECT COUNT(mail_ID) as top_one, archived_by, archived_date
FROM test
GROUP BY mail_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
    FROM test
    GROUP BY mail_id
    ORDER BY total DESC
    LIMIT 1
)


top_one     archived_by     archived_date
2           Tina             2012-10-10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select mail_id, archived_by, archived_date, cnt
from (
select mail_id, archived_by, archived_date, count(*) cnt
from Mail_Archives
group by mail_id, archived_by, archived_date
order by archived_date desc)
where rownum = 1;
```

Or (if you like window functions)

```
select mail_id, archived_by, archived_date, cnt from (
select mail_id, 
       archived_by, 
       archived_date, 
       row_number() over (order by archived_date desc) rn,
       count(*) over (partition by mail_id, archived_by, archived_date) cnt
from Mail_Archives)
where rn = 1;
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2b77d/29)

---

**UPDATE** assuming that you want the max date and count for only the mail_id

```
select mail_id, archived_by, archived_date, cnt from (
select mail_id, 
       archived_by, 
       archived_date, 
       row_number() over (order by archived_date desc) rn,
       count(*) over (partition by mail_id) cnt
from Mail_Archives)
where rn = 1;
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9b5d8/8)

Comment: But pls check in this link, slightly i modified the datas http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9b5d8/1                                     Now the Cnt is Coming as "1" but my expected result should be "2" becuase Mail ID "002" having two entries